# How to display today button in bootstrap datepiker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I use this code for display today button but dont show .I delete mindate and then display today button but don't work and In this case I can select previews year that is mistake. Please advice

```
$("#ReturnDateM_flight").datepicker({
    regional: '',
    showButtonPanel: true,
    isRTL: true,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    todayHighlight: true,
    minDate: 1,
    dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd"
});
```

[image]

Comment: OP : I think you need to re-word your question. It is tough to understand what you have got and where you need clarification.

Comment: You can see that in top image today button do not dispaly . How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try This, minDate:0 and maxDate:0 for active only current date.

```
$("#ReturnDateM_flight").datepicker({
regional: '',
showButtonPanel: true,
isRTL: true,
numberOfMonths: 2,
todayHighlight: true,
minDate:0,
maxDate:0,
dateFormat: "yy/mm/d});
```

Or try this if you want to see current date + next date

```
$( "#ReturnDateM_flight" ).datepicker({
    regional: '',
    showButtonPanel: true,
    isRTL: true,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    todayHighlight: true,
    minDate: new Date(),
    dateFormat: "yy/mm/d"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    showButtonPanel: true,
    buttonImage: buttonCalendar,
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: ""
});
```

and call this js code in the pages where you have the calendar.

```
$.datepicker._gotoToday = function(id) { 
    $(id).datepicker('setDate', new Date()).datepicker('hide').blur(); 
};
```